# JSON-LD additional properties, that are not in the dictionary schema.org

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Plan to refactor the data JSON format to JSON-LD, using a dictionary schema.org.

The problem is that we need to pass additional properties that are not in the dictionary schema.org, we cannot abandon these properties because there it is technical metadata that is used in the logic of our AJAX sites.

The question of having the properties are not in the dictionary schema.org, create problems for indexing AJAX our site, or search bot will simply ignore the properties he does not know and it does not affect indexing?

Comment: parsers usually don't mind about extra stuff they don't know. they usually ignore it. of course the right thing to do is not to clutter linked data with technical metadata which have only meaning to you. this may help you to see what google sees and what not https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bots will simply ignore those properties. If you don't map them to URLs (for example by setting them explicitly to `null` in the context), they are effectively invisible for a JSON-LD processor. See http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#advanced-context-usage for more details

Comment: Yes, but all the undefined properties, google testing-tool gives an errors.

Comment: Read the error. It just says that the property isn't recognized - which is to be expected given you defined it yourself.

Comment: @S.A.N you can define everything you want that is not in schema.org as http://schema.org/Thing or http://schema.org/Intangible - if you have properties for something which schema.org does not cover then you can either not add schema.org data to that property but leave the HTML there and the parser will ignore it and not give an error.